# MTLS AWS with 4096 RSA imported key

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain-name, aws-certificate-manager

I have a 4096 imported key in ACM, but now I need create an API Gateway domain name with MTLS using that certificate.

For that i am using the Imported or private certificate option in the domain configuration.

I have created a certificate with the same domain in ACM to configure the Ownership verification certificate requested by AWS

But after that, the first error i got was:

[error not dubjects covered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXBeG.png)

after create the wild card, and all subjects, now i am getting this error:

[Aws error exist certificate with differnt issuer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJtje.png)

But i don't use the certificate anywhere else.

I need create the MTLS with a imported certificate with 4096 RSA key size

Comment: Welcome Dufresny, I think the message is not about using the cert somewhere else, but having two certificates from different CAs (certificate authorities) for the same domain. This might happen if you have an older certificate from an external CA and now recreate the same certificate in the AWS Cert Manager. See also [this AWS repost FAQ](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-mtls-certificate-subject). //EDIT: Formatting...

Comment: In that order of ideas, is it not possible to perform mtls with an imported certificate signed by a CA different to AWS? because Aws request to me the Ownership verification certificate

Comment: How/where are you going to use an AWS ACM certificate to perform mTLS? I don't think AWS actually supports doing mTLS with any of the services that are integrated with AWS ACM, except API Gateway, and it doesn't support storing the verification certificate in ACM.

Comment: Yes, I mean in AWS API GW Service in -> Custom Domain Name, when I try to add the MTLS and WHen i am selecting the Certificate type, AWS give me 2 options:
Public ACM certificate and Imported or private certificate.

With public ACM all works fine with MTLS, but with an imported certificate with a 4096 RSA key in ACM and signed for other CA I have the errors in my question

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

The problem was that i had in Aws Certificate Manager with Domain name:

1. the imported certificate (domain name xxxx.com)
2. The Ownership verification Certificate (domain name xxxx.com) -> Required by AWS for MTLS of a imported Certificate in ACM
3. Other certificate issued by AWS (domain name xxxx.com)

Then that was the message that AWS show me: conflict with certificate with differnt issuer, The isuue was generated for the certificate of point 3

When i deleted the certificate of the point 3, the problem was solved